# Php change the order of the date

Tags: php, date

I am trying to display the date that I send by `$_GET`, my url format is for example `http://127.0.0.1/index.php?date=01/08/2018`.

The result is `08-01-2018` it change the order of the day and the month why ?

```
$orginal_date= $_GET['date'];
$date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($original_date));
echo $date;
```

Comment: Read [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php#120063) "Date values separated by slash are assumed to be in American order: m/d/y"

Comment: If the given answer don't help: can you clarify the date format that you've used? The example date `01/08/2018` can be parsed in at least two different formats

Answer (score 3):

It automatically parses the date with format `m/d/Y` (american format). You could use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to specify your format:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_GET['date']);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

Documentation:

- [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)
- [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
list($month, $day, $year) = explode("/", $_GET["date"]);
$date = sprintf("%d-%02d-%02d", $year, $month, $day);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you may be assuming how php will use strtotime and convert to a timestamp. By default it thinks that 01/08/2018 is Jan 8 2018.  There is a method date_create_from_format that you can tell it the format you are expecting and then you can format that to however you want it to look like.

`$orig = $_GET['date'];
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $orig);
echo date_format($date, 'd-m-Y');`

`//result is 01-08-2018`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
list($month, $day, $year) = explode("/", $_GET["date"]);
echo date('d-m-Y',mktime(0, 0, 0, $month,$day, $year));
```